# Issue in response in main $state between development and production server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have a problem with routes in Angular.

In dev.version of my project, everything works perfect, but on production, I have some problems with creating main $state.
See screenshots.

This is normal $state, which perfect works in my dev.

[image]

But this is awful $state, which is on production.

[image]

I don't have any idea how fix this problem. Help me please.

Comment: How can we have an idea without a single line of code??

Comment: Provide more info and your code. What you tried so far and results etc..

Comment: What code you interest? How I create main route?

Comment: Yes. Staet by including the routes os the app. And show the function scope were you output the console.log